# How to reference SAS variable with CATS in PROC SQL?

Tags: sql, sas, sas-macro

Very basic thing I can't seem to figure out. Columns in a particular table are numbers with underscores in front of them, I have a number stored in a macro variable and the name of the column I want to use is that number with an underscore. Say the number is 9, when I write the following code I get a column where each observation is _9 rather than column _9 from that dataset.

```
    proc sql;
    create table TM1 as
        select cats("_",&rat_as_num) from default_data;
    quit;
```

Comment: What exactly does &rat_as_num resolve to? Please post he output of : `%put &rat_as_num.;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CATS returns a string, not a variable name. So the variable name will not matter, you get a string with _RAT_AS_NUM_VALUE.

To return a variable name use %SYSFUNC() instead,

```
data test;
_9 =  4;
run;


%let rat_as_num=9;

proc sql;
create table test2 as
select %sysfunc(cats(_, &rat_as_num)) from test;
quit;


proc print data=test2;
run;
```

Per @Richards comments this also works:

```
proc sql;
create table test2 as
select _&rat_as_nun from test;
quit;
```

Comment: Note sure why you don't just go with `select _&rat_as_num. from test`.  The whole `sysfunc(cats` route seems round about.

Comment: Yup, that's a simpler solution by far!